# Under what conditions will the generated Top Level Statement class be $Program?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, toplevel-statement

I've always been under the assumption that the class generated by Top Level Statements was a hidden, inaccessible class. For example:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(2);

partial class Program
{
    public static string abc = "def";
}
```

When ran in SharpLab.io using the [default branch](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgjAdLAnACgEwEoDcBYAUHgBwEMAnAFwEsiAbAAilXpgHY8BvPWr+gZiYDYmABlpEARgGNaAXloAiYAFMAZnJy4AvkA=) or the ["C# 9: Top-level statements (27 May 2020)" branch](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGUCWBbADgGwgAUEB7AcwSm2QBoATEAagB8ABARgDpOBOACgBMASgDcAWABQU3FAQxMUfAAI2g1RwDsUgN5TlB1QGYNANg0AGZVGABjZQF5lAInoQwziZIC+QA==), the generated C# will be

```
// [ ... using and assembly attributes ... ]
internal static class $Program
{
    private static void $Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }
}
internal class Program
{
    public static string abc = "def";
}
```

<sup>Though it's interesting to note that the default branch emits `<Program>$` not `$Program` and `<Main>$` not `$Main`.</sup>

However, [it's known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71058076/1043380) you can use a `partial` class `Program` to augment the generated class. Modifying the code to print the field...

```
System.Console.WriteLine(abc);
partial class Program { public static string abc = "def"; }
```

... and running again with *some particular* newer branch ["C# Next: File types (5 Jul 2022)"](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRgJYBsKpgTwAcUAaAExAGoAfAAQEYA6BgTgAopgBjASgG4AsAChCUBDAxQsAAloAmWfQDs0gN6yAzIoBsigAzTOXaQF5pAIjIQw5vtIC+woA) will generate the combined class:

```
// [ ... using and assembly attributes ... ]
internal class Program
{
    public static string abc = "def";

    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

<sup>For the record, I do not know what C# compiler version is used with this branch, I'm assuming some version of C# 10.</sup>

However, the [default branch](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgjAdLAnACgIYCMDGBKA3AWACgAHVAJwBcBLVAGwAIoAmRmAdnoG9GBmVgNlYAGehkz0AvPQBEwAKYAzabnoBfIkA===) or ["C# 9: Top-level statements (27 May 2020)" branch](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGUCWBbADgGwgAUEB7AcwSm2QBoATEAagB8ABARgDpOBOACijAAxgEoA3AFgAULigIYmKPgAEbAExqOAdhUBvNQGYtANi0AGFUOEqAvCoBE9CGAfiVAXxlA=) will produce a syntax error, where the `abc` field cannot be found.

I'm having problems reproducing this issue outside of Sharplab. Creating a .NET 5 / C# 9 (the version that this feature [came out in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements)) console application locally compiles and runs:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework> <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```
System.Console.WriteLine(abc);
partial class Program { public static string abc = "def"; }
// I have SDK 5.0.408 and runtime 5.0.14,15,17 installed, along with others for core 3.1 and .NET 6
```

[Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nFKPbM) will also compile the code, but it only allows me to choose .NET 6, and the C# version is unknown.

Assuming this isn't a bug with Sharplabs, my assumption would be that the class emitted changed for different C# 9 compilers. Sharplabs might be showing *the original* C# 9 compiler, but my computer might be running a newer version.

The only other evidence I can see is an edit in the [dotnet/csharplang git repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/commit/d7c3bef81a34aaa417cd47675fdd2e73ef092d27#diff-a18fd8818ea93281948d26740ec76d542595a3bc52c075075937d8a12c175013L150-R152) that changed the documented emitted class from `static class $Program` to `partial class Program`. Even though this file is in the "proposal" folder, it does seem to be the same file that is [published to Microsoft's documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20220411230010/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements), so at some point in the past it was documented that the class name was `$Program`.

Why does Sharplab compile the first code block into two classes, and why can't it accept a partial class to augment the entry point class? Was this feature modified after release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now reflected in the [Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics) feature spec:

> The type is named "Program", so can be referenced by name from source code. It is a partial type, so a type named "Program" in source code must also be declared as partial.

Which was changed from the [previous](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/1dbcfb485ce782bb4cb6e7bbbdeb264bcb9641b7/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements.md) via [this commit](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/commit/d7c3bef81a34aaa417cd47675fdd2e73ef092d27) on Jun 22, 2022:

> Note that the names "Program" and "Main" are used only for illustrations purposes, **actual names used by compiler are implementation dependent and neither the type, nor the method can be referenced by name from source code**.

My guess is that the change was done to support [integration testing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-6-9) with the new hosting model in .NET 6 and the first mention of this possibility there is dated [Oct 21, 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/aafdca64fc73938c1b9878018e77d6ecca91bcce/aspnetcore/migration/50-to-60-samples.md#project-file-csproj).

So in the nutshell - any modern .NET 6+ compiler should generate `Program` class, for earlier versions you should not rely on the naming (though .NET 5 is EOL now and this is not very relevant).